# What are the first bits of a bitstring, for instance generated using SHA-256?

Tags: sha-256

I have a string that generates from SHA-256

```
x = fea5f97f9ca1e1a0a2ae344f4e12a3ab0c4d9221e6bb5d70bc567e39f8fbc3d5
```

What's are the first 10 bits are of the value of `x`?

Comment: The output seems to be hexadecimal. Each character here is stored in 4 bits. You need 2 & 1/2 characters to get 10 bits

Answer (score 2):

The question's title (now) asks "What are the first bits of a bitstring". That's unambiguous if the bits are presented individually in a chronological order, or in writing in a context where there is a conventional reading order, like left to right.

But the body of the question is about "a string that generates from sha256". That's to be read as SHA-256, defined by [FIPS 180-4](https://nvlpubs.nist.gov/nistpubs/FIPS/NIST.FIPS.180-4.pdf#page=4). It's an algorithm which outputs a "bit string" of $256$ bits, and they are not immediately identifiable.

The body of the question has `x =`  followed by $64$ characters all either digits or letters from `a` to `f` (in uniform case, here lowercase), which is $16=2^4$ characters. That hints the result of SHA-256 is encoded in [hexadecimal](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Hexadecimal), with each character encoding 4 bits (notice $256=64\times4$). This is one of several common representations of bitstrings as characters.

There are several different and incompatible ways to convert hexadecimal to bits, but fortunately, in the case of SHA-256, one is specified in 3.1 subparagraph 2 on [page marked 7 of FIPS 180-4](https://nvlpubs.nist.gov/nistpubs/FIPS/NIST.FIPS.180-4.pdf#page=12) (a must read). In summary, the most significant bits are first, be it at the nibble (4-bit), byte (8-bit), or word (32-bit in case of SHA-256) level.

Thus to find the first $i$ bits for the SHA-256 hash given, we can

- Check that $0\le i\le256$, otherwise what's asked is undefined.
- Take the first $\lceil i/4\rceil$ characters (where $\lceil r\rceil$ with $r\in\mathbb R$ is the smallest integer at least $r$); here $i=10$, thus $\lceil i/4\rceil=3$, thus we take `fea`
- Write each of these characters (in reading order) as 4 binary digits per big-endian convention, per

  ```
  0 -> 0000     4 -> 0100     8 -> 1000     c -> 1100
  1 -> 0001     5 -> 0101     9 -> 1001     d -> 1101
  2 -> 0010     6 -> 0110     a -> 1010     e -> 1110
  3 -> 0011     7 -> 0111     b -> 1011     f -> 1111
  ```
- That results in a string of $4\,\lceil i/4\rceil$ bits (here the 12 bits `111111101010`), of which we keep the first $i$ bits (here `1111111010`).

This applies to all hashes of the SHA family (replacing $256$ with their output width). Absent other specification, it's reasonable to apply it to other standard hashes which output width is a multiple of $32$ (or even $8$ or $4$) bits. That's debatable for MD5, since it uses little-[endian](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Endianness) convention in byte order within a $32$-bit word. And I would not blindly extend it to other quantities used in cryptography and also represented in hexadecimal, such as integers as used in RSA.

Answer (score 0):

Since this is about into programming and needs to be closed or migrated, here in Python with big-endian;

```
def LSBBits( hexData, lsbs):

    scale = 16 ## equals to hexadecimal

    inBinary = bin(int(my_hexdata, scale))[2:]
    inBinary = inBinary.zfill(256)
    return inBinary[len(inBinary)-lsbs:]

def MSBBits( hexData, mbsb):

    scale = 16 ## equals to hexadecimal

    inBinary = bin(int(my_hexdata, scale))[2:]
    inBinary = inBinary.zfill(256)
    return inBinary[:mbsb]

my_hexdata = "fea5f97f9ca1e1a0a2ae344f4e12a3ab0c4d9221e6bb5d70bc567e39f8fbc3d5"


print( LSBBits(my_hexdata, 10))
print( MSBBits(my_hexdata, 10))
```

And the program outputs.

```
1111010101
1111111010
```

[Big-and little-endianness](https://www.tutorialspoint.com/big-endian-and-little-endian) is another story. [NIST assume big-endianness](https://nvlpubs.nist.gov/nistpubs/FIPS/NIST.FIPS.180-4.pdf).

Comment: I'm afraid this answer is about the off-topic part of the question.

Comment: @fgrieu I've expected a migration... Yes, due to an artifact, the zfill was causing it, removed, thank.